# M2: Using LayoutProcessor, block taking up entire block instead of being a child

Tags: magento2, jslayout

I am trying to use `LayoutProcessor` to include a block within the section `before-place-order` on the M2 Checkout.

Currently, I already have two blocks within there (a comments block and an order attachment block), both of those use the standard `layout.xml` inclusion so no issues with additional blocks and sorting.

However being new to using the `LayoutProcessor`, whenever I try to include the new block, it ends up taking the entire block over, removing the other two blocks.

The setup I am using:

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['before-place-order'] =
        [
            'component' => 'uiComponent',
            'displayArea' => 'before-place-order',
            'children' =>
            [
               ...
            ]
        ]
```

I believe it looks obvious to me that I am declaring it to essentially take up the `before-place-order` spot instead of telling it to be a child of it, but any method I've tried to change that to being a child, doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with the simple function `array_merge_recursive`.

Example code:

```
/**
 * Checkout LayoutProcessor after process plugin.
 *
 * @param LayoutProcessor $processor
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $processor, $jsLayout)
{
    $beforePlaceOrderLayout = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
    ['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['before-place-order']['children'];
    //Your custom field
    $fields['custom_info_note'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/textarea',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'custom_info_note',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textarea',
            'options' => [],
            'id' => 'delivery_comment'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'custom_info_note.custom_info_note',
        'label' => 'Comment',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 20,
        'id' => 'custom_info_note'
    ];
    //Array Merge
    $additionalLayout = array_merge_recursive($beforePlaceOrderLayout, $fields);

    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['before-place-order']['children'] = $additionalLayout;
    return $jsLayout;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]